# In Angular, bind attribute from scope variable *before* ngModel binds the input’s `value`

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

In my Angular app, I defined a custom slider directive that wraps [`<input type="range">`](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range#.3Cinput_type.3D.22range.22.3E). My custom directive supports `ngModel` to bind the slider’s value to a variable. The custom directive also requires a `fraction-size` attribute. It does a calculation on the value and then uses the result to set the `step` value of the wrapped `<input>`.

I am seeing a bug when I combine these two features – `ngModel` and my bound attribute value. They are run in the wrong order.

Here is a demonstration:

```js
angular.module('HelloApp', []);

angular.module('HelloApp').directive('customSlider', function() {
    var tpl = "2 <input type='range' min='2' max='3' step='{{stepSize}}' ng-model='theNum' /> 3";
    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: tpl,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            fractionSize: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            scope.stepSize = 1 / scope.fractionSize;
            
            scope.$watch('theNum', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(newValue);
            });
            
            ngModelCtrl.$render = function() {
                scope.theNum = ngModelCtrl.$viewValue;
            };
        }
    };
});

angular.module('HelloApp').controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
 $scope.someNumber = 2.5;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="HelloApp" ng-controller="HelloController">
    <h3>Custom slider</h3>
    
    <custom-slider ng-model="someNumber" fraction-size="10"></custom-slider>
    
    <h3>View/edit the slider’s value</h3>
    <input ng-model="someNumber"></input>
</div>
```

The above slider should start at the middle, which represents 2.5. But it actually starts all the way at the right (representing 3). The slider fixes itself and allows the value 2.5 if you drag it, or if you change its bound value by editing the text field.

I have figured out why this is happening in the demonstration – I just don’t know how to fix it. Currently, when a new custom slider is dynamically added to the page, the wrapped `<input>`’s `step` is undefined, and defaults to 1. Then `ngModel` sets the value to 2.5 – but since `step` is 1, the value in the `input` is rounded to 3. Finally, `step` is set to `0.1` – too late for it to matter.

**How can I ensure that the `step` attribute’s value is bound *before* `ngModel` sets the input’s `value`?**

In the example above, the slider is on the page at page load. In my real code, multiple new sliders are added dynamically. They should all bind their `step` and `value` in the correct order whenever they are added.

### A workaround I don’t like

A workaround is to hard-code the `step` in the template instead of setting it dynamically. If I were to do this, my custom slider directive would have no use, and I would remove it and just use an `<input>` directly:

```html
<input type="range" min="2" max="3" step="0.1" ng-model="someNumber">
```

If I use that, the slider’s `value` is set correctly, without rounding. But I want to to keep my custom directive, `customSlider`, so that the calculation of `step` is abstracted.

### Things I tried that didn’t work

- Changing the order of the `step` and `ng-model` attributes in the template doesn’t have any effect.
- I started trying to add a `compile` function, instead of just having a `link` function. But I can’t set `stepSize` in `compile` because `scope` isn’t available during the compile phase.
- I tried splitting my directive’s `link` function into pre-link and post-link functions. But whether I set `scope.stepSize` in `pre` or in `post`, the page works as before.
- Manually calling `scope.$digest()` right after setting `scope.stepSize` just throws `Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`.
- I don’t think custom directive priorities are a good fit for this, because there is only one custom directive involved. My binding of `step`’s value isn’t a custom directive, it is just raw `{{}}`-binding. And I think binding `step` is a simple enough task that it shouldn’t be wrapped in its own directive.

Comment: As Icycool [noted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293611/in-angular-bind-attribute-from-scope-variable-before-ngmodel-binds-the-input#comment54388616_33294138), there is an open Angular issue for this, [#6726 “ng-model does not set initial value and position of input\[type=range\]”](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking [@pixelbits' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33295145/1319998) of direct DOM manipulation further, I wouldn't have another `ng-model` on the inner input at all, and instead always set/get the properties on the input directly

- You have one abstraction level to think about when setting/getting values from the input. Raw DOM events and elements.
- As such you are not limited to what Angular allows on such elements (indeed: what it does seems to not be able to handle your use case without work-around). If the browser allows it on the range input, you can do it.
- Have 2 ngModelControllers in play on the one UI widget that sets one value can get a bit confusing, at least for me!
- You still have access to the outer ngModelController pipeline and all its functionality regarding parsers and validators, if you need/want to use it.
- You save from having an extra watcher (but this could be a micro/premature optimization).

See an example below.

```js
angular.module('HelloApp', []);

angular.module('HelloApp').directive('customSlider', function() {
    var tpl = "2 <input type='range' min='2' max='3' /> 3";
    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: tpl,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            fractionSize: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var input = element.find('input');          
            input.prop('step', 1 / scope.fractionSize);

            input.on('input', function() {
              scope.$apply(function() {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(input.prop('value'));
              });
            });

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function(value) {
               input.prop('value', ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});

angular.module('HelloApp').controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
    $scope.someNumber = 2.5;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="HelloApp" ng-controller="HelloController">
    <h3>Custom slider</h3>
    
    <custom-slider ng-model="someNumber" fraction-size="10"></custom-slider>
    
    <h3>View/edit the slider’s value</h3>
    <input ng-model="someNumber"></input>
</div>
```

Also available at http://plnkr.co/edit/pMtmNSy6MVuXV5DbE1HI?p=preview

Comment: The `scope.$apply` seems to be unnecessary – the `input` handler still works even without the `scope.$apply`. I think this is because `ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue` triggers a `$digest` when it runs. Is it a good practice to use `scope.$apply` around DOM manipulation “just in case”, even when it is unnecessary with the current code?

Comment: @RoryO'Kane I don't think `setViewValue` triggers a digest, because a) when testing without it, after sliding range the model change wasn't visible in the "View/Edit" part; and b) if it was triggering it unconditionally there would be a console error in my example due to triggering it when it's already running, and there isn't

Comment: I thought `$setViewValue` started a digest because [its docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) say “a `$digest` is only triggered once the `updateOn` events are fired …”, but maybe it means that it doesn’t `$digest` at all if no `updateOn` attribute is set. Still, when I edit your example to remove the surrounding `scope.$apply`, the model change is visible when I drag the slider. Maybe it’s a browser-specific thing – I’m using Chrome. I’ll use `$apply` in my code to be safe.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Ah you're right about it not being needed. I'm not sure what I was doing when I first tested it...

Answer (score 2):

In your `link` function, manipulate the DOM by adding the `step` attribute.

You can also simplify your binding with the outer `ngModel` by putting `theNum: '=ngModel'` in `scope`.

```js
var app = angular.module('HelloApp', []);

app.directive('customSlider', function () {
    var tpl = "2 <input type='range' min='2' max='3' ng-model='theNum' /> 3";
    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: tpl,
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            fractionSize: '=',
            theNum: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            var e = element.find('input')[0];
            
            var step = 1 / scope.fractionSize;
            e.setAttribute('step', step);
            
            scope.$watch('fractionSize', function (newVal) {
                if (newVal) {
                    var step = 1 / newVal;
                    e.setAttribute('step', step);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

angular.module('HelloApp').controller('HelloController', function($scope) {
    $scope.someNumber = 2.5;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="HelloApp" ng-controller="HelloController">
    <h3>Custom slider</h3>
    
    <custom-slider ng-model="someNumber" fraction-size="10"></custom-slider>
    
    <h3>View/edit the slider’s value</h3>
    <input ng-model="someNumber"></input> {{ someNumber }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do it, but adding a timeout to your main controller solves the issue.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.someNumber = 2.5;
});
```

Edit: While it seems like a dirty hack at first, but note that it is common for (final) $scope variables to be assigned later than templates, because of additional ajax calls to retrieve the values.

Comment: I’m afraid this doesn’t work for me. In my real app, sliders are added to the page by an `ngRepeat` directive, in reaction to the user-initiated appending of numbers onto an array. So my app’s equivalent of `$scope.someNumber` always exists before the creation of the slider that edits it. And my app is completely offline anyway, so timeouts would be out-of-place.

Comment: Looks like it is raised as an [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6726) in angular. You might want to refer to temp solutions in there.